# Does Garmin provide Step count of the user in their API?

Tags: garmin

I went through the Garmin's Connect API documentation [here](https://developer.garmin.com/garmin-connect-api/features/) But nowhere it mentions that they provide Step count of the user. This data is critical for my app.

Can someone kindly answer this question, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wonder if this might help?... includes "steps" and more...

https://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq/api-docs/
Class: Toybox::ActivityMonitor::History

Hope it helps,
Chip

Comment: Thanks that was helpful

Answer (score 2):

you need to use Health API, you will find all the info there:

https://developer.garmin.com/health-api/overview/